# Ionic loading indicator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Here a sample [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNxvOm) to explain my needs.

Basically I'm running a 2-pages Ionic application.

Page 1 is nothing but an hyperlink to page 2.

Page 2 reads data from an external source and requires some time (2 seconds).

I'd like to show a loading indicator while page 2 is "loading" that inhibits every user action on that page. Is there any good patterns to achieve this goal? I can probably use scope variables such as `showPage` and *angularJs* `ng-show` or something like that, but I would avoid to copy this pattern in every page.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [angular-block-ui](https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui).

It is very simple to implement in your project. Once you've referenced the css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path-to-block-ui/angular-block-ui.min.css"/>
```

and the javascript:

```
<script src="path-to-block-ui/angular-block-ui.min.js"></script>
```

you can add the dependency to your module:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['blockUI'])
```

It uses [interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) for long http calls. You can see how it works in the **Block on HTTP requests** in the [examples](http://angular-block-ui.nullest.com/#!/examples/manual-blocking-examples) page.

In your situation things are slightly different cause there's no http request there (I know, it's a demo) so you have to force the ui block manually.
You can change the service injecting the dependecy to blockUI:

```
.factory('MyService', function($q, blockUI) { ... })
```

and call `blockUI.start();` right before the long running process and `blockUI.stop();` when the promise is resolved.

```
.factory('MyService', function($q, blockUI) {
    var items = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
    return {
        all: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            blockUI.start();
            setTimeout(function() {
                deferred.resolve(items);
                blockUI.stop();
            }, 2000);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
})
```

See your modified sample [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPprGz?editors=101).

In one of my apps I've used another angular module called [angular-loading-bar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar). I guess it is the most popular these days. This one works with interceptors as well but it doesn't block the UI.

The third option is to use the ionic `$ionicLoading` service.

You have to do a little bit of extra work here as this service only show a loading indicator and blocks the interface.

You can create an interceptor:

```
var app = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

app.config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($rootScope) {
    return {
      request: function(config) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:show')
        return config
      },
      response: function(response) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide')
        return response
      }
    }
  })
})
```

which listens to http requests and broadcasts an event `loading:show`.
When the server has responded with some data the interceptor broadcasts `loading:hide`.

Your app would intercept those events when the app runs:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $ionicLoading) {
  $rootScope.$on('loading:show', function() {
    $ionicLoading.show({template: 'foo'})
  })

  $rootScope.$on('loading:hide', function() {
    $ionicLoading.hide()
  })
})
```

Comment: whoa...you answered the same time I post my solution :)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that :-)

Comment: *blockUI* looks very clever and more concise than *ionicLoading*. Very helpfull answer!

Comment: Glad I've helped @c.bear. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: [$ionicLoading](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicLoading/) is what I was looking for.